# CURL invoking API with SSL

Tags: php, curl, ssl, ssl-certificate

I am using `CURL` to invoke an API with self signed public key in **.pfx** extension

```
function execute_curl($string,$URL)
{
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $URL);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: text/xml','SOAPAction:"http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/SendDoc"'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $string);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, TRUE);

    $ch_result = curl_exec($ch);

    return $ch_result;
}
```

I cannot set the `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` to **FALSE** for security purpose, anyone can show me how I can properly add the certificate along with its password into curl? *EDIT* I am not even sure if that is the solution for it, so far I am only getting no response from it. Any additional solution or ways to make it work is very much appreciated.

Also, I am trying to make it work on 2 environment, my dev environment which is in windows and also my test server environment which is in fedora, should the certificate be in different format?

Comment: Using CURLOPT_SSLKEY and CURLOPT_SSLKEYPASSWD

Comment: I already did, it does not work. If you can provide me with an answer and sample on how to do it, if it will work I will mark it as an answer